# what is this broken piece on this laptop (satellite c855d-13g)

Tags: hardware-failure, laptop-repair

This laptop came to me for fixing:

- It turned on
- Nothing on the screen
- No beeps

I tried connecting it to an external monitor and pressing the shortcuts to switch monitors but nothing worked.

I opened it up to disconnect the main monitor and check if it would automatically switch to an external monitor.

I found this broken part which I cannot identify and I'm wondering if this may be the culprit, so do you know  what it is?

[cap im holding was on top of the broken part]

[image]

UPDATE:
I unplugged the monitor and voila it changed to the second monitor, the weirdest thing is i connected the monitor again and it worked! i witnessed it not working before so im baffled.... could me removing the broken part have fixed it?

Comment: Can you make another picture that does not have reflecting light?

Comment: oh sure here are a bunch https://s23.postimg.org/keqtk690b/20161227_004818.jpg https://s30.postimg.org/gcy2oezkx/20161227_003533.jpg

Comment: another one https://s27.postimg.org/5kw3bdjo3/20161227_004945.jpg

Comment: `could me removing the broken part have fixed it`. It is not impossible. Unfortunately, I do not recognize this part. My advice to you is to find manual for this laptop and check what this broken part is.

Comment: that is quite a specific hardware question.. you could also try the toshiba section on notebook forum http://forum.notebookreview.com/forums/toshiba.9/  or the toshiba forum itself.

Comment: You would need the schematic to determine if the broken part is the reason the display doesn't work.  The schematic will tell you what part it is by the way, and will allow you to diagnose the display problem, and we can't help locate it for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's actually quite obvious what this part is.

Note the proximity and orientation of the part to the edge of the board.

If you line up the case with the board, you will see a slot.

Got what it is yet?

Example, not the exact same model:[image: Got image from here: https://www.aliexpress.com/store/product/10pcs-8pin-Micro-SD-Card-Slot-Connector-fit-for-Phone-Tablet-Laptop-MotherBoard-TF-Card-Slot/218781_32688632207.html][link](https://www.aliexpress.com/store/product/10pcs-8pin-Micro-SD-Card-Slot-Connector-fit-for-Phone-Tablet-Laptop-MotherBoard-TF-Card-Slot/218781_32688632207.html)

It's the SD / Multi card reader.

With it removed, the only problem the laptop should have is that the card reader won't work.

My guess is that it was shorting out something, which led to the video fault. As long as that didn't damage any other components, there should be no further issues.

I'd advise whoever it was who gave you the laptop to be more careful inserting things into the laptop in the future.